# how to execute an action if the before_action returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, actioncontroller

I know that with the following code:

`before_action :signed_in?, only: [:new]`

the action `new` will be executed if the `signed_in?` returns true, but instead if I want the `new` action to be executed when `signed_in?` returns false what do I have to do? Do I have to create a new method called, for instance, `not_signed_in?`?

Here it is my `signed_in?` method

```
def signed_in?
  !@current_user.nil?
end
```

Comment: Are you sure it won't run if `signed_in?` returns `false`? Why would it do that?

Comment: what's the goal of `before_action`? Is it to block the execution of an action if it returns false?

Comment: No. Its purpose is to prepare something before your method executes.

Comment: No, it's just new `before_filter` name, as far as I know.

Comment: can you paste your signed_in? method? OR is it a default devise method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

before_action doesn't work as you think - it doesn't prevent action to be executed if callback returns `false`. 
I would solve your problem in a little bit different manner, for example:

```
before_action :redirect_to_root, :if => :signed_in?, :only => :new

# ...
private
def redirect_to_root
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. Thanks
p.s. pozdrawiaj jakub jalbzykowski ode mnie! ;)

Comment: @antox LOL how do you know Jakub? And how do you know I know him? :) Facebook? :P

Comment: FB knows everything! :) How do I know him? uuu it's a long story, maybe he could tell you

Answer (score 8):

```
before_action :new, unless: -> { signed_in? }
```

alltough i think its better to redirect in the action which was called.

```
def your_action_called
  redirect_to :new unless signed_in?
  [...code ...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover all other methods with
`before_action :signed_in?`
except new action, you'b better to use `:except` instead of `:only`
 like this:
`before_action :signed_in?, except: :new`