# before_action with the same callback but different condition not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is my `before_action` in controller

```
before_action :redirect_to_home, unless: :logged_in?, only: %i[destroy]
before_action :redirect_to_home, if: :logged_in?, only: %i[new create]
```

My purpose is redirect to home when call `new` and `create` action for authenticated user and `destroy` for unauthenticated user

this is my `redirect_to_home` callback

```
def redirect_to_home
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

this is my `logged_in?` method

```
def logged_in?
  p 'HELLO FROM LOGGED_IN'
  session[:user_id].present?
end
```

when I ran the `destroy` test spec nothing printed out to the console but when I swap the line and run the `destroy` test spec again everything looks fine but `new` and `create` test spec are broken.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ref [this](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#after-filters-and-around-filters)

```
Calling the same filter multiple times with different options will not work,
since the last filter definition will overwrite the previous ones.
```

You can do following

```
before_action :redirect_to_home, only: %i[new create destroy]
```

And in controller

```
def redirect_to_home
  if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    redirect_to destroy_path #You have to use actual destroy path here.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

before_action doesn't prevent action to be executed if callback returns false.

You can make another method:

```
def ensure_user_is_logged_in
  unless logged_in?
    redirect_to_home
end
```

Then you can use it before_action like this:

```
before_action :ensure_user_is_logged_in, only: %i[new, create]
```

It will redirect to home if the user is not logged in.

You can refer to this for more info:
[how to execute an action if the before_action returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120485/how-to-execute-an-action-if-the-before-action-returns-false)